# Laravel htaccess issue on OSX Snow leopard

Tags: macos, .htaccess, laravel

Im having an issue with Laravel's htaccess file on my OSX setup.
I have been running the applications perfectly on WAMP, but when i transferred to my Mac i started to get issues.

the htaccess is default

```
    # Apache configuration file
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

    # Note: ".htaccess" files are an overhead for each request. This logic should
    # be placed in your Apache config whenever possible.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

    # Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and
    # features. "+FollowSymLinks" must be enabled for this to work symbolically.

     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
     </IfModule>

    # For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
    # "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
     </IfModule>
```

I am using V-Hosts to have a XXXXXXX.laravel URL.

Ive added the URL to my config file and left the index blank.

Everytime i visit the homepage XXXXXXX.laravel i get the homepage, but when i navigate to XXXXXXX.laravel/test i get a 404.

If i try XXXXXXX.laravel/index.php/test it works ok.

If i add index.php to the index in the config file, it just appends the index.php to my links.

Any ideas??
Thanks
Adam,

Comment: Is this Laravel 3 or Laravel 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Apache **httpd.conf** and check if you have **mod_rewrite** turned on

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and not turned off like this

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Yes i have LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by putting rewrite conf in the `<Directory />` block of my apache conf file for the virtual host.
I am using Laravel 4.